# How to fix Win2003 Task Scheduler Error 0x8007000d: The data is invalid after re-joining domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

After re-joining this Windows 2003 Server box with the domain, all 20+ Scheduled task jobs were unable to start.

> An error has occurred attempting to retrieve task account information.
>   You may continue editing the task object, but will be unable to change
>   task account information.

The specific error is:

> Task Scheduler Error 0x8007000d: The data is invalid.

Neither is it possibly to change the account name under which the individual Scheduled task jobs do run.

I have tried to remove all jobs, close the Scheduled tasks window, and erase all `b42*` files as suggested in [MS KB822904](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/822904/the-attempt-to-retrieve-account-information-for-the-specified-task-fai).

How to fix this error without re-creating all 20+ jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve problems with the task scheduler:

- stop the Task Scheduler service
- on folder `c:\windows\Tasks` remove the system attribute with `attrib -s c:\windows\Tasks`
- go to the properties of `c:\windows\Tasks` and add the office\administrations group
- go to "Advanced", then "Owner" and replace the owner of the sub-containers and objects with the office\administrations group
- set the system attribute back through `attrib +s c:\windows\Tasks`
- launch the Task Scheduler service again

Answer (score -1):

1. Download the old and hard to find Microsoft [`systaskfix.exe`](http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/03_w13/120113/SysTaskFix.zip) utility
2. Run `> systaskfix.exe -fix`

Comment: Running a random .exe from the internet without knowing what it does is not really a solution for a problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Microsoft most often produces **closed source** and does not explain what their software does.

Comment: True, but at the point of my comment your answer didn't reflect that this is a Microsoft tool. Add a proper description, maybe even a link to documentation if it can still be found (maybe via web archive?) and it will become a good answer. Just a link to a .exe file on a phony download site is not trustworthy.